# Add separator (divider) in Symfony2 Sonata Admin?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

How would you add separator/divider to the side menu in Dashboard in Sonata Admin?

[image: Sonata Admin menu divider]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that you can do that from the configuration. What you could do is create a sonata_admin_custom.css file and include it in the configuration

```
sonata_admin:
    assets:
        stylesheets:
          ...
          - css/sonata_admin_custom.css
          #relative to web root
```

Then in that file

```
.sidebar-menu .treeview:nth-of-type(2) {
border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd; 
}
```

I've tested it on my site and it works, make sure you look at the [documentation for sonata admin](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/configuration.html) and get the rest of the stylesheets. If you don't include the `stylesheets:`, sonata admin uses the default. If you want to make changes like this, make sure you include all the default files that are listed in the documentation. When you update sonata admin, get the update configuration from their documentation also.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly an easy way of doing that.... I should have thought about :nth-child() selector myself!